# encryption and decryption

Tags: c#, java, encryption

i want to encrypt string in java and decrypt the same string in C# and vice versa .how to do it .and which is best encryption method

Thanks

aswan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go with a standard encryption method. The algorithm used will be secure, the result will be portable and there are libraries for many platforms. 3-DES or AES would be good choices.

Comment: hi i am using aes encryption with 16 blocks if i giving more data it is showing block size exception i can i resolve it

Answer (score 1):

The word "best" is different things to different people, and strongly influence the choices available to you.

If speed is extremely important to you, then just add one to every character value, send it, and subtract one again.    In other words send "ABC" as "BCD".

Answer (score 0):

AES is supported in the .NET framework in the Rijndael class, you can find the documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx.  When encrypting a string you will want to make sure that the way you choose your key is a secure method, and make sure it is stored in a secure place as well.  In any encryption scheme the weakest link is the key.